# Basic Django form response

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am new to Django and looking to build a quick form with a response.

I am trying to build a form which would ask the user to input his name when the user clicks submit the page should reload and just say "Hello .

urls.py

```
class Question1Form(forms.Form):
n = forms.CharField(max_length=100,
                    widget=forms.TextInput(
                        attrs={'placeholder': 'Number', 'class': 'form-control'}))
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Question1Form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        result = [Question1Form.ans()]
        return HttpResponse(Question1Form.n)
  else:
    form = Question1Form()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

index.html

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.non_field_errors }}
  <div class="form-row form">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      {{ form.n.errors }}
      {{ form.n }}
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

So how the code s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call instance field, not class field and get value from validated(cleaned) data (see [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#field-data)):

```
return HttpResponse(form.cleaned_data['n'])
```

If you want to reload the same template with `n` value:

```
return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form, 'n': form.cleaned_data['n']})
```

and at the template add:

```
{% if form.is_valid %}
    <p> Hello {{ n }} </p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Question1Form(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    result = form.save()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'created': True})
```

Then in your HTML you can say

```
{% if created %}
    <p> Hello </p>
{% endif %}
```

*edit* I see now you have no action in your form.

So you need to point to that view in your URLS.py.
for example.

```
from myapp import views as app_views
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns =[
    url(r'^my_form/$', app_views.home, name='save_form'),
]
```

And then add the action to your form.

```
<form action="{% url 'save_form' %}" method="post" class="form">
```